# Bit representation of float using an int pointer

Tags: c++, floating-point

I have the following exercise:

> Implement a function void float to bits(float x) which prints the bit
>   representation of x. Hint: Casting a float to an int truncates the
>   fractional part, but no information is lost casting a float pointer to
>   an int pointer.

Now, I know that a float is represented by a sign-bit, some bits for its mantissa, some bits for the basis and some bits for the exponent. It depends on my system how many bits are used.

The problem we are facing here is that our number basically has two parts. Let's consider `8.7` the bit representation of this number would be (to my understanding) the following: `1000.0111`

Now, float's are stored wit a leading zero, so `8.8` would become `0.88*10^1`

So I somehow have to get all the information out of my memory. I don't really see how I should do that. What should that hint hint me to? What's the difference between a integer pointer and a float pointer?

Currently I have this:

```
void float_to_bits() {
    float a = 4.2345678f;
    int* b;
    b = (int*)(&a);
    *b = a;

    std::cout << *(b) << "\n";
}
```

But I really don't get the bigger picture behind the hint here. How do I get the mantissa, the exponent, the sign and the basis? I also tried playing around with the bit-wise operators >>, <<. But I just don't see how this should help me here, since they won't change the pointers position. It's useful to get e.g. the bit representation of an integer but that's about it, no idea what use it'd be here.

Comment: Your understanding is wrong. 8.7 is not going to be stored as "1000.0111". Your first step is to actually research how floating point values are represented on your platform. Until you actually know for fact how they're stored, trying to write any code is a waste of time because you don't know what you should expect. Of course, it makes a lot of sense to blindly dump the raw bytes that make up a `float` first, and see if you can decipher it yourself, and/or verify the information that your research uncovered.

Comment: ah true, it's a long time ago I did that. Gonna quickly refresh it. But it is familiar but I'd still have the same problem. I don't understand the hint at all. How would I get e.g. the mantissa?

Comment: Given a single byte, how do you get the lowest bit out of it? Getting the mantissa involves the same exact approach.

Comment: Can you elaborate the question? How is the byte given? On paper? In c++, if so, how? In c++ I'd work with << and >> and & but that's not the point. I can e.g. also get the bit wise representation of an integer - but I don't see how to get the actual byte of infromation from my float. My problem is rather "getting" the data than working with it.

Comment: Open your C++ book to the chapter that explains casting, and it should have plenty of examples of how to convert a pointer to one type to a pointer to a different type. So, you simply obtain a pointer to your float and convert it to a pointer to an `unsigned char`. You know what `sizeof(float)` is, so that's how many `unsigned char`s you can access via your converted pointer, and you're pretty much done, at that point.

Comment: Yeah I did think about chars but the hint talks about integers. :/ So I don't think the idea is to use chars. I'm going to reread the casting and floating point chapter anyway. thanks

Comment: The author of the exercise may have intended you to convert a pointer to `float` to pointer to an `int` and then display the value of that `int`, thus revealing the bits that represent the `float`. This would be an improper way to do it in C++, but that does not disprove this was the author’s intent—a number of people mistakenly use such a method. It is, however, proper in C to convert the pointer to a pointer to `unsigned char` or `std::byte` and then display the values of the bytes that represent the `float`. (`char` should be avoided due to sign issues.)

Comment: thanks, so if I get that right: My float in single precision takes up 32 bits. So I have 32 zeros and ones. If I now do the above, I get a "32 bit integere"? Like the whole zero and one sequence of my 32 bit float is "converted" into one big integer number? So I can calculate the bit representation of that big integer number and then get the sign bit, exponent bits, mantissa bits?

Answer (score 4):

The hint your teacher gave is misleading: casting pointer between different types is at best implementation defined. However, `memcpy(...)`ing an object to a suutably sized array if `unsigned char`  is defined. The content if the resulting array can then be decomposed into bits. Here is a quick hack to represent the bits using hexadecimal values:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstring>

int main() {
    float f = 8.7;
    unsigned char bytes[sizeof(float)];
    std::memcpy(bytes, &f, sizeof(float));
    std::cout << std::hex << std::setfill(‘0’);
    for (int b: bytes) {
        std::cout << std::setw(2) << b;
    }
    std::cout << ‘\n’;
}
```

Note that IEEE 754 binary floating points do **not** store the full significand (the standard doesn’t use *mantissa* as a term) except for denormalized values: the 32 bit floats store

- 1 bit for the sign
- 8 bits for the exponent
- 23 bits for the normalized significand with the non-zero high bit being implied

Comment: thanks, I'm going to look into it  but I don't think I should use chars and/or arrays.

Comment: Yes. What your teacher suggested will lead to undefined behavior, though: trying to read a value through a pointer or reference to a different type is a violation of the strict aliasing rules. The use of `memcpy()` is “magic” as compilers need to recognize it and expose the bytes even though it would normally be a violation of the aliasing rules.

Comment: The C++ standard doesn’t make any guarantees on what the values of the bytes will be, i.e., there is no restriction on the representation of built-in types. However, it does guarantee that `memcpy()` to a byte array and back will retain the original value (without aliasing issues). Thus, the bytes will old something which will kind of represent the bits of the original value. `reinterpret_cast<...>(...)`ing pointers doesn’t have mych defined behavior but lots of traps causing undefined behavior and generally at best implementation defined behavior.

Comment: This answer and the comments by its author misstate the C++ rules. Reading through a pointer to a difference type is not uniformly a violation of the aliasing rules. C++ 2017 (draft n4659) 6.10 [basic.lval] 8 specifically allows reading through `char`, `unsigned char`, and `std::byte` types, along with some other cases. And that, not “magic,” is what makes `memcpy` a proper method, along with the fact that its semantics are inherited from C, which specifies that it copies characters. C++ also specifies some semantics for pointer conversions; they are not wholly implementation-defined.

Answer (score 2):

The hint directs you how to pass the Float into an Integer without passing through value conversion.
When you assign floating-point value to an integer, the processor removes the fraction part. `int i = (int) 4.502f;` will result in i=4;

but when you make a int pointer (`int*`) point to a float's location,
no conversion is made, also when you read the `int*` value.

to show the representation, i like seeing HEX numbers,
thats why my first example was given in HEX
(each Hexa-decimal digit represents 4 binary digits).

but it is also possible to print as binary,
and there are many ways (I like this one best!)

Follows an annotated example code:
Also available @ [Culio](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e77e721b4145ab0f)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   float a = 4.2345678f; // allocate space for a float. Call it 'a' and put the floating point value of `4.2345678f` in it.
    unsigned int* b; // allocate a space for a pointer (address), call the space b, (hint to compiler, this will point to integer number)
    b = (unsigned int*)(&a); // GREAT, exactly what you needed! take the float 'a', get it's address '&'.
    //                          by default, it is an address pointing at float (float*) , so you correctly cast it to (int*).
    //                          Bottom line: Set 'b' to the address of a, but treat this address of an int!

    // The Hint implied that this wont cause type conversion:
    // int someInt = a; // would cause `someInt = 4` same is your line below:
    // *b = a; // <<<< this was your error.
    // 1st thing, it aint required, as 'b' already pointing to `a` address, hence has it's value.
    // 2nd by this, you set the value pointed by `b` to 'a' (including conversion to int = 4);
    // the value in 'a' actually changes too by this instruction.

    cout << a << " in binary " << bitset<32>(*b)  << endl;
    cout << "Sign    " << bitset<1>(*b >> 31) << endl; // 1 bit (31)
    cout << "Exp     " << bitset<8>(*b >> 23) << endl; // 8 bits (23-30)
    cout << "Mantisa " << bitset<23>(*b) << endl; // 23 bits (0-22)
}
```

Comment: hmm I don't think that's what they wanted. I really think I should do some bit wise operation and just read the data out of the memory directly. But I'm just guessing, thanks though. Gonna look into it. also, what's hex?

Comment: @xotix Hex is "hexadecimal" which is a shorthand way of writing binary that takes 75% less text. Check wiki.

Comment: @doug Yeah, I am familiar with hex, there's no question about hex. I meant the variable hex he used before, I couldn't find it anywhere in the code. Thought maybe it's a flag but it didn't look like it. Anyway, he updated the answer anyway. :)

Comment: hex is actually a formatter defined in stdlib std::hex... it is misleading to think it was a variable. see http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/hex/

Comment: FWIW, for normalized numbers only, I guess the 23 bit mantissa (significand is the preferred term) from the float should be or-ed with 0x800000 to add the hidden bit. And the exponent should be un-biased too (IIRC by subtracting 127).